# Yii 2.0.14 update with Kartik gridview

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I updated a project from Yii2 version 2.0.6 to 2.0.14. Everything is working fine, just the Kartik gridview is throwing this error

**Setting unknown property: yii\bootstrap\ButtonDropdown::containerOptions**

1. I have already tried composer install again and composer update.
2. Checked the composer asset plugin for Yii2 as well its on the latest    version.
3. Checked the Yii2 change logs for any compatibility issue, found nothing for this case.
4. Checked the [Yii2 documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.2/yii-bootstrap-buttondropdown) as well as the core files in vendor, the code is exactly as per the documentation.

Comment: What kartik grid view version are you using? Probably you need to update it also in your composer.json.

Comment: My composer require section is as follows: 
       "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        ....
        "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "^1.0",
        ...

Comment: Are you using `yii\bootstrap\ButtonDropdown` in your grid view columns or `\yii\grid\ActionColumn` for your action column. please share the code for any of the two scenarios.

Comment: I haven't added particular drop down myself, I am using simple configuration like in kartik gridview demo at http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo, with export.

Answer (score 0):

`yii\bootstrap\ButtonDropdown::$containerOptions` property was introduced in version 2.0.1 of `yii2-bootstrap` extension - make sure that you have it installed:

```
composer require "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap:~2.0.1" --update-with-all-dependencies
```

Comment: I have to check other dependencies as well for the compatibility. The command is throwing this error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
 - Conclusion: don't install yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.8..... to 2.0.1

Comment: That actually confirm the cause of this issue - you have `yii2-bootstrap` v2.0.0, which does not have this property. Upgrade is the only clean way of solving it.